# StackExchange theme problem: is the website hacked?

Tags: discussion

Every time I check the website, I see the following theme. And the mouse cursor has tails now. Does any one else have the same problem? Is the site hacked?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No. It’s something that happens from time to time when holiday hats arrive or April Fools day arrives or just no particular reason.

See the links on the sidebar here for an explanation or the question this is a duplicate of.

The Time Machine control in the top bar will help navigate back to last week’s design or back to the 90’s as you please.